# How to align a large image centre in a smaller container

Tags: html, css

Say I have a 800x400 image (could change) and I want to put it in a 800x300 container (with `overflow: hidden`). How do I make it vertically centre (so that the top 50px and bottom 50px are hidden).

Note that the image size could change on my page so I can't use tricks like `margin-top: -50px`. But I can set the `width: 100%` to make it always fill the entire container horizontally, in this case we can assume the image to always be taller than the container.

For example:

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid blue; /*Visually show where the div is.*/
}
.container > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/800x400" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks very much for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **object-fit** property.

> The object-fit CSS property sets how the content of a replaced element, such as an img or video, should be resized to fit its container.

For the `img` will need to define:

- the *width*
- the *height*
- the *object-fit*
- the *object-position*

More info 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid blue; /*Visually show where the div is.*/
}
.container > img {
  object-fit: cover; /* Cover  means that the img will fill the box and preserve its aspect ratio  */
  object-position: center; /* Position of the image in it's parent */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="//via.placeholder.com/800x800" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually find the `object-position: center` is not required here and it still works fine for me.

Comment: @TuoWang You are right, the initial value is `50% 50%`. Be aware that `object-fit` won't work in Internet Explorer. You will need  polyfill for IE. Have a look at Can I Use https://www.caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for the edit, I should have done it !

Comment: I was happy to do so. I'm the one who updated the question to add the code (using what the OP said in text combined with your answer and the other answer) as part of the process of getting it reopened. Editing your answer to make sure my changes to the question didn't invalidate your answer, or make it look like you weren't following the question's lead, is really something that should be part of the process of my updating the question. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow doesn't notify answer authors when the question is edited. Thus, there's really no way for you to know the question was edited.

Answer (score 1):

this could be easily done by adding the image as a background instead of `<img ...`

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/600);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

---

a second solution could be using `object-fit` and `object-position`. you also have to set the images width and height to `100%`:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.container > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" />
</div>
```